# Am I finding $f(x,y)$ correctly?

Tags: calculus

> If $\dfrac{df}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{x+y}$ and $\dfrac{df}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{x+y}$. Find $f(x,y)$.

What I did was: I multiplied $df/dx$ by the inverse of $df/dy$, which gives me $1$.

I want to know if my workings is correct.
Thanks

Comment: Looks a look like a logarithm function.

Comment: How do I get the solution, please? I need to submit it tomorrow and I don't have a textbook

Comment: You should use partial derivative notation: $\partial f/\partial y$, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $f(x,y)$ is a two-variable function, so $f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $f_y=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are partial derivatives (notation with curved d).

Then:
$$f(x,y)=\int f_xdy=\int \frac1{x+y}dy=\ln (x+y)+g(x)+C_1;\\
f(x,y) =\int f_ydx=\int \frac1{x+y}dx=\ln (x+y)+h(y)+C_2;\\
g(x)=h(y)=0, C_1=C_2;\\
f(x,y)=\ln (x+y)+C.$$